# How to create a dynamic @Html.ActionLink with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying create a dynamic `@Html.ActionLink` with JQuery and I cannot do this.

How could I do this ?

trying

```
$('#tableView > tbody').empty();   
    if (data["CategoriaProduto"].length > 0) {
        $.each(data["CategoriaProduto"], function (i, cp) {
            var editLink = $('@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", "CategoriaProduto"), new {id = ' + cp.id + '}');           

            $('#tableView > tbody:last-child').append('<tr>'
                                                    + '<td class="text-capitalize small">' + cp.descricao + '</td>'
                                                    + '<td class="col-md-1">' + editLink + '</td>'
                                                    + '</tr>');
        });
    }
```

Comment: You cant. Razor code is evaluated on the server before its padded to the view - your javascript variable does not exist at that point. You can use `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", "CategoriaProduto")` to generate the 'base' url and then append the route value in the script by modifying its `href` attribute

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is you can't.

The command `@Html.ActionLink()` must be resolved on the server before the page is sent to the client's browser. jQuery will only operate in the client's browser.

What you can do however is render it in the browser and then copy the resulting html eg. `<a href="/Edit/CategoriaProduto">My Link</a>` or whatever the output turns out to be, and using that format in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

for each row you can specify and auto id, and these id pass as parameter to Controller. and this is dynamic url creation.